# AutoCAD 2017 LT SQL Support

Tags: sql, autocad

We are about to trial our GIS/LIS team moving onto AutoCAD LT as the functionality they use is minimal. I've installed it as a pilot but we seem unable to find how to connect to an SQL source.

Just wanted to confirm that it is even capable of connecting to an SQL source? Seems that the 'dbconnect' command is missing / does nothing?

AutoDesk has absolutely no mention of it on their site or support forum!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Moving to AutoCAD LT from what?  Were you able to connect to SQL previously, and how?

Comment: To edit and store data in a spatial database (Oracle,MS SQL, PostGIS) you will need AutoCAD Map 3D see this old but relevant matrix (top of page 3) http://www.raptsoft.com/documents/autocad_map_comparison_to_autocad_and_autocad_lt.pdf LT is for LighT and you will be limited in your workflows.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it seems that you cannot connect to DB using AutoCAD LT. In the [About the dbConnect Manager](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-8374B198-C4F9-485B-8062-8996D8571304-htm.html), AutoCAD LT is not mentioned under the software that have this function.

[image]

Comment: correct AutoCAD 20xx or higher is required to connect using DB Connect Manager but there is still restrictions until AutoCAD 3D Map is purchased, where you can convert from many GIS formats to AutoCAD formats.

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks for sharing the document. This confirms that connecting to DB is unsupported using AutoCAD LT as it is, without upgrading to AutoCAD Map.